# yarn build fails on line one no matter what's in there

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, yarnpkg

I have a react project bootstrapped with create-react-app and came across a build error I can't really get a hang off it.

The project includes two css files, one `index.css` the second is `overrides.css` which is also the file the compiler complains about. Both included in `index.js`.

Now when I run `yarn build` in my project directory, I get the following compiler error:

```sh
maxi@tuerkasten:~/projects/calendar-ui$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.10
warning package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/overrides.css
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 15


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
maxi@tuerkasten:~/projects/calendar-ui$
```

This is what `overrides.css` looks now:

```css
.ui.celled.grid > .column:not(.row),
.ui.celled.grid > .row > .column.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 14vh;
}

/* @todo: find a way to solve this more elegant */
.ui.celled.grid > .column:not(.row),
.ui.celled.grid > .row > .column.no-min-height {
  min-height: 5vh;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* calendar days without month */
.calendar-day.notfirstday {
  width: 30.08px;
  height: 30.08px;
}

.ui.menu:not(.vertical) .right.item.no-padding-margin {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.ui.container.backend-container {
  margin-left: calc(var(auto)+200px) !important;
  margin-top: calc(var(auto)+50px) !important;
}

/* remove require asterisk */
.ui.form .required.field > .checkbox.remove-require:after {
  content: '';
}
```

The strange thing is, no matter what I do on line one in `overrides.css`, the error remains the same and the development server `yarn start` is just running fine.

Comment: can you post the 'dist' script and/or gulpfile.js content?

Comment: also, this file should not be of type .scss instead of css?

Comment: yarn install - did you do this?

Comment: @danielarend I haven't ejected the project yet. This should still be using react-scripts when building. I guess it's using webpack under the hood. Right, the file type should be css not scss.

Comment: @DarthJS yes, did a fresh rm -rf node_modles/ yarn.lock and reinstalled all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the compiler does not like no whitespaces in css calc functions.

I've just changed this

```css
.ui.container.backend-container {
  margin-left: calc(var(auto)+200px) !important;
  margin-top: calc(var(auto)+50px) !important;
}
```

to that

```css
.ui.container.backend-container {
  margin-left: calc(var(auto) + 200px) !important;
  margin-top: calc(var(auto) + 50px) !important;
}
```

and the compiler is fine

Comment: ...but this doesn't work in Chrome. Is it my lack of css knowledge or a bug?

Comment: I am having the same problem as you. Did you find the reason behind the error?